# Decimal Round Off issue in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using default decimal to string converter with rounded off values using provision provided by Apple.

```
String(format: "%.02f", 0.345)
```

But if I round off **0.345** getting **0.34** value where as if I round off **0.445** getting **0.45**.

Is this a bug in SDK or it's a expected behaviour?

**Note:** I know the alternate solution is using NumberFormatter but want to check issue with String formatter.

Comment: @user2864740 Please check my question. for 0.445 it's working correct. Issue is with 0.345

Answer (score 2):

This is an artifact of floating point binary representation.

The decimals `0.345` and `0.445` cannot be precisely represented as a floating point binary number. So, the actual value is very close, but not quite the same.

Specifically, a double-precision `0.345` is actually `.3449999....`, and a double-precision `0.445` is actually `0.4450000000000000066613...`.

Hence the result you're getting.